# Define type with multiple library definitions C#

Tags: c#

I have a new feature I am trying to add to an existing (working) program. This new feature requires a library reference, which includes a definition for the type `Device`, which I am already using...
The original code was:

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {
                devices.Add (e.Device);
});
```

To specify which definition I was intending to reference, I changed this to:

```
Robotics.Mobile.Core.Bluetooth.LE.Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread ( () => {
                devices.Add (e.Device);
);
```

However, this now throws the error:

> Robotics.Mobile.Core.Bluetooth.LE.Device does not contain a definition for 'BeginInvokeOnMainThread'

How can I work around this?

Comment: try to go to definition of `Robotics.Mobile.Core.Bluetooth.LE.Device` class (Press F12) , is there a method `BeginInvokeOnMainThread ` ?

Comment: @tchelidze Nope, ['BeginInvokeonMainThread`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/MonoTouch.Foundation.NSObject.BeginInvokeOnMainThread/p/MonoTouch.Foundation.NSAction/) is a core command in the Xamarin framework. I want something which is functionally identical to the top code snippet

Comment: I am not experienced in Xamarin, but as i see `BeginInvokeOnMainThread ` method is declared in `Xamarin.Forms.Device` class.

Comment: @tchelidze yes, so how can I reference it, whilst not leaving Device to be ambiguous?

Comment: try this `Xamarin.Forms.Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {
                devices.Add (e.Device);
})`

Comment: @tchelidze but Device is defined in the Robotics.Core... Path?